# Query Tuning--Snapshot dump-

Tags: teradata

I have a big query which needs some tuning. I can't see any place where there is any scope for optimizing. The recommended and required stats are all collected. Could you please have a look and suggest. Its doing a **snapshot dump** when submitting the query through informatica.Below is the error we are getting:
**3610       Internal error: Please do not resubmit the last request.  SubCode, CrashCode:   0,  3651**

```
    SELECT       
TD.INFORMATION_DATE AS INFORMATION_DATE , 
TD.PROCESSING_DATE AS PROCESS_DATE ,
NULL AS EXCEPTION_REASON_POA , 
NULL AS EXCEPTION_REASON_CUST ,
NULL AS EXCEPTION_REASON_SITE , 
NULL AS EXCEPTION_REASON_SIC ,
FRET.FIC_REPORTING_ENTITY_ID AS REPORTING_ENTITY_ID , 
NULL AS REPORTERS_REFERENCE_NO ,
'CTR' AS REPORT_CODE , 
NULL AS REPORT_SUBMISSION_DATE , 
TD.TRANSACTION_EFFECTIVE_DATE AS TRANSACTION_DATE ,
TD.TRANSACTION_AMT AS TRANSACTION_AMOUNT , 
TD.TRANSACTION_CURRENCY_CODE AS TXN_CURRENCY_CODE ,
CASE 
WHEN CFT.FUNCTION_TYPE_CODE IN ( 'CDK' , 'MDK' , 'CW' , 'CWA' ,
    'CDMK' , 'CWC' , 'CWR' , 'CWS' , 'QDAK' , 'QE' , 'TCS' , 'CDF' ,
    'BNRP' , 'NRW' , 'FBS' , 'BNTF' , 'BNSP' , 'TOTP' , 'TOTB' ,
    'BNSL' , 'CDCK' ) THEN 'CASH OUT' 
ELSE 'CASH IN' 
END   AS TRANSACTION_DIRECTION , 
TD.TRANSACTION_SOURCE_TYPE_DESC AS TXN_TYPE ,
TD.FUNCTION_TYPE_DESC AS FUNCTION_CODE , 
TD.TRANSACTION_BRANCH AS TXN_BRANCH ,
TD.ACCOUNT_BRANCH AS ACCOUNT_BRANCH , 
TD.ACCOUNT_NUMBER AS ACCOUNT_NUMBER ,
TD.BRAND_TYPE_DESC AS ACCOUNT_TYPE , 
TD.TRANSACTION_ADDRESS AS TXN_ADDRESS ,
TD.TRANSACTION_CITY_NAME AS TXN_CITY , 
TD.TRANSACTION_POSTAL_CODE AS TXN_POSTAL_CODE ,
TD.TRANSACTION_COUNTRY_CODE AS TXN_COUNTRY_CODE , 
NULL AS TXN_PROVINCE ,
NULL AS CUSTOMER_TYPE_GROUP_CODE , 
CASE  
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME <> 'SIG' THEN IC_N.NAME_INITIALS 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS CUSTOMER_TITLE , 
CASE  
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME <> 'SIG' THEN IC_N.GIVEN_NAME 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS FIRST_NAME , 
CASE 
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME <> 'SIG' THEN IC_N.SURNAME 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS LAST_NAME , 
CASE  
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME <> 'SIG' THEN IC_N.BIRTH_DATE 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS BIRTHDATE , 
CASE 
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME <> 'SIG' THEN IC_N.COUNTRY_OF_NATIONALITY_CODE 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS NATIONALITY , 
CEC.E_MAIL_USER_ID AS EMAIL_ADDRESS , 
CASE  
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME <> 'SIG' THEN IC_N.INDV_OCCUPATION_TYPE_DESC 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS OCCUPATION ,
CPC_BP.TELEPHONE_DIAL_CODE AS BUSINESS_DIAL_CODE ,
CPC_BP.TELEPHONE_NUM AS BUSINESS_PHONE_NUMBER , 
CPC_HP.TELEPHONE_DIAL_CODE AS RESIDENTIAL_DIAL_CODE ,
CPC_HP.TELEPHONE_NUM AS RESIDENTIAL_PHONE_NUMBER , 
OC.PRACTICE_NUMBER AS PRACTISE_NUMBER ,
CASE 
 WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME <> 'SIG' THEN IC_N.FIC_IDENTIFICATION_TYPE_CODE 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS ID_TYPE , 
CASE  
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME <> 'SIG' THEN IC_N.IDENTIFICATION_NUM 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS ID_NUMBER , 
CASE  
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME <> 'SIG' THEN IC_N.COUNTRY_PASSPORT_ISSUED_NAME 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS PASSP_ISD_COUNTRY_CODE , 
CAC_RA.ADDRESS_NAME_1 AS PHYSICAL_ADDR_LINE ,
CAC_RA.CITY_NAME AS PHYSICAL_CITY , 
CAC_RA.POSTCODE_AREA AS PHYSICAL_POST_CODE ,
NULL AS BRAND_SHORT_NAME_ACCOUNT , 
CASE  
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME <> 'SIG' THEN IC_N.UNIQUE_ID_IN_SOURCE_SYSTEM 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS CUSTOMER_KEY , 
TD.ACCOUNTABLE_INSTITUTION_CODE AS ACCOUNTABLE_INSTIT_CODE ,
TD.SOURCE_SYSTEM_DESC AS SOURCE_SYSTEM , 
TD.TRANSACTION_QTY AS TXN_COUNT_TOT ,
OC.SIC_TYPE_DESC AS TYPE_OF_BUSINESS , 
CASE  
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME = 'SIG' THEN IC_N.UNIQUE_ID_IN_SOURCE_SYSTEM 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS SIG_CUSTOMER_KEY , 
CASE  
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME = 'SIG' THEN IC_N.CUSTOMER_TYPE_CODE 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS SIG_CUSTOMER_TYPE_CODE , 
CASE  
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME = 'SIG' THEN IC_N.NAME_INITIALS 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS SIG_TITLE , 
CASE  
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME = 'SIG' THEN IC_N.GIVEN_NAME 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS SIG_FIRST_NAME , 
CASE  
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME = 'SIG' THEN IC_N.SURNAME 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS SIG_LAST_NAME , 
CASE  
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME = 'SIG' THEN IC_N.BIRTH_DATE 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS SIG_BIRTHDATE , 
CASE  
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME = 'SIG' THEN IC_N.COUNTRY_OF_NATIONALITY_CODE 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS SIG_NATIONALITY , CEC.E_MAIL_USER_ID AS SIG_EMAIL_ADDRESS ,
CASE 
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME = 'SIG' THEN IC_N.INDV_OCCUPATION_TYPE_DESC 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS SIG_OCCUPATION , 
CPC_BP.TELEPHONE_DIAL_CODE AS SIG_BUSINESS_DIAL_CODE ,
CPC_BP.TELEPHONE_NUM AS SIG_BUSINESS_PHONE_NUMBER , 
CPC_HP.TELEPHONE_DIAL_CODE AS SIG_RESIDENTIAL_DIAL ,
CPC_HP.TELEPHONE_NUM AS SIG_RESIDENTIAL_PHONE_NUM , 
OC.PRACTICE_NUMBER AS SIG_PRACTISE_NUMBER ,
CASE 
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME = 'SIG' THEN IC_N.FIC_IDENTIFICATION_TYPE_CODE 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS SIG_ID_TYPE , 
CASE  
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME = 'SIG' THEN IC_N.IDENTIFICATION_NUM 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS SIG_ID_NUMBER , 
CASE 
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME = 'SIG' THEN IC_N.COUNTRY_PASSPORT_ISSUED_NAME 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS SIG_PASSP_ISD_CNTRY_CODE , 
CAC_RA.ADDRESS_NAME_1 AS SIG_PHYSICAL_ADDR_LINE ,
CAC_RA.CITY_NAME AS SIG_PHYSICAL_CITY , 
CAC_RA.POSTCODE_AREA AS SIG_PHYSICAL_POST_CODE ,
NULL AS ERROR_STATUS , 
NULL AS BATCH_ID , 
NULL AS FORMAT_TYPE ,
NULL AS BATCH_SORT , 
TD.TRANSACTION_BRANCH AS ACCT_TXN_SITE_ZERO ,
CASE 
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME = 'SIG' THEN IC_N.CUSTOMER_TYPE_CODE 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS CUSTOMER_TYPE_CODE , 
NULL AS RESUBMISION_STATUS , 
NULL AS BATCH_ERROR_STATUS ,
NULL AS FIC_RESUBMIT , 
TD.TRANSACTION_COUNTRY_CODE AS COUNTRY_CODE_FROM_CTR ,
CASE 
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME = 'SIG' THEN IC_N.COUNTRY_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS SIG_COUNTRY_CODE , 
TD.TRANSACTION_CUSTOMER_KEY AS TXN_CUSTOMER_KEY ,
TD.PARTY_DETAILS AS REPORT_PARTIES , 
NULL AS STATUS_COMMENT ,
NULL AS PROPERTY_SIZE , 
TD.SIZE_UNIT_OF_MEASUREMENT AS SIZE_UNIT_OF_MEASUREMENT ,
NULL AS REGISTRATION_DATE , 
OC.ORG_REGISTRATION_NUM AS REGISTRATION_NUMBER ,
NULL AS ITEM_ID_NUMBER , 
NULL AS ADDITIONAL_COMMENTS , 
TD.ITEM_TYPE_CODE AS ITEM_DESCRIPTION ,
NULL AS PREVIOUS_REGISTERED_TO , 
NULL AS CURRENT_REGISTERED_TO ,
TD.ESTIMATED_VAL_AMT AS ESTIMATED_VALUE , 
NULL AS DISPOSED_VALUE ,
NULL AS REPORTING_PERSON , 
TD.TRANSACTION_COUNTRY_CODE AS BANK_COUNTRY ,
TD.ITEM_TYPE_CODE AS ITEM_TYPE , 
NULL AS ITEM_MAKE , 
NULL AS ITEM_REGISTRATION_NUMBER ,
CASE 
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME = 'SIG' THEN IC_N.SURNAME 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS MOTHERS_NAME , 
CASE 
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME = 'SIG' THEN IC_N.SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER , 
CAC_EA.ADDRESS_NAME_1 AS EMPLOYER_ADDRESS_ID ,
CPC_BP.TELEPHONE_NUM AS EMPLOYER_PHONE_ID , 
NULL AS SWIFT_CODE ,
NULL AS NON_BANKING_INSTIT_FLAG , 
NULL AS SIG_ROLE , 
TD.POST_TRANS_ACC_BAL_AMT AS BALANCE ,
TD.ACCOUNT_NAME AS ACCOUNT_NAME , 
NULL AS INT_BANK_ACCOUNT_NUMBER ,
NULL AS PRIMARY_CUSTOMER_FLAG , 
TD.TRANS_STATUS_TYPE_CODE AS STATUS_CODE ,
OC.FIC_ENTITY_LEGAL_FORM AS INCORPORATION_LEGAL_FORM , 
CWAC_BW.UNIVERSAL_RESOURCE_LOCATOR AS INTERNET_WEB_SITE ,
OC.INVOLVED_PARTY_NAME AS TRADING_NAME , 
NULL AS DATE_OF_INCORPORATION ,
NULL AS DATE_BUSINESS_CLOSED , 
NULL AS BUSINESS_CLOSED_FLAG ,
CAC_PA.ADDRESS_NAME_1 AS POSTAL_ADDRESS_LINE_2 , 
CAC_PA.CITY_NAME AS POSTAL_ADDRESS_LINE_3 ,
NULL AS TYPE_OF_FUNDS , 
NULL AS TXN_CONDUCTOR , 
NULL AS TYPE_OF_FUNDS_DESC ,
CASE 
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME = 'SIG' THEN IC_N.DECEASED_FLAG 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS DECEASED_FLAG , 
CASE  
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME = 'SIG' THEN IC_N.IDENTIFICATION_ISSUE_DATE 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS ID_ISSUE_DATE , 
CASE  
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME = 'SIG' THEN IC_N.INDV_TEMP_RESIDENCE_EXP_DATE 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS ID_EXPIRY_DATE , NULL AS ISSUING_AUTHORITY_NAME , 
CASE  
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME = 'SIG' THEN IC_N.DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DATE 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS DATE_OF_DEATH , 
OC.VALUE_ADDED_TAX_NUM AS VAT_REGISTRATION_NUMBER ,
NULL AS SOURCE_OF_WEALTH , 
CASE  
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME <> 'SIG' THEN IC_N.GIVEN_NAME 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS MIDDLE_NAME , TD.ACCOUNT_BRANCH AS DOMICILE_SITE_CODE ,
CASE 
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME <> 'SIG' THEN IC_N.COUNTRY_PASSPORT_ISSUED_CODE 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS COUNTRY_PASSPORT_ISSUED , 
CASE  
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME <> 'SIG' THEN IC_N.COUNTRY_OF_RESIDENCE_CODE 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS COUNTRY_OF_RESIDENCE , 
CASE  
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME <> 'SIG' THEN IC_N.NAME_INITIALS 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS INITIALS , 
CPC_BP.TELEPHONE_NUM (NAMED ASPHONE_EXTENSION_NUMBER ) ,
NULL AS STR_CLASIFICATION_IND , 
NULL AS TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION ,
NULL AS TXN_AUTHORISOR , 
TD.TRANSACTION_EFFECTIVE_DATE AS VALUE_DATE ,
NULL AS TRANSACTION_MODE_COMMENT , 
TD.PARTY_DETAILS AS PARTY_DETAILS ,
NULL AS GOODS_SERVICES_LINKED , 
NULL AS TELLER_NUMBER , 
TD.AR_OPEN_DATE AS DATE_ACCOUNT_OPENED ,
OC.ORG_TAX_IDENTIFIED_NUM AS TAX_NUMBER , 
CASE  
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME <> 'SIG' THEN IC_N.GENDER_DESC 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS GENDER , 
CASE  
WHEN IC_N.SOURCE_FILE_NAME <> 'SIG' THEN IC_N.COUNTRY_OF_BIRTH_NAME 
ELSE NULL 
END   AS COUNTRY_OF_BIRTH , 
TD.TRANSACTION_CURRENCY_CODE AS CURRENCY_CODE ,
TD.SOURCE_SYSTEM_CODE AS SOURCE_SYSTEM_CODE , 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP( 6 ) AS DW_LOAD_TIMESTAMP ,
NULL AS DW_INVALIDATED_TIMESTAMP 
FROM X_TRANS.TRANSACTION_DAILY TD 
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_REF.COMBD_FUNCTION_TYPE CFT 
ON  CFT.FUNCTION_TYPE_DESC = TD.FUNCTION_TYPE_DESC 
AND   CFT.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE = '3499-12-31' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_REF.FIC_REPORTING_ENTITY_TYPE FRET 
ON  TD.ACCOUNTABLE_INSTITUTION_CODE = FRET.FIC_REPORTING_ENTITY_ID 
AND   FRET.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE = '3499-12-31' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_TRANS.INDIVIDUAL_CURRENT IC_N 
ON  TD.INVOLVED_PARTY_ID = IC_N.INVOLVED_PARTY_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_TRANS.CUSTOMER_EMAIL_CURRENT CEC 
ON  TD.INVOLVED_PARTY_ID = CEC.INVOLVED_PARTY_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_TRANS.CUSTOMER_PHONE_CURRENT CPC_BP 
ON  TD.INVOLVED_PARTY_ID = CPC_BP.INVOLVED_PARTY_ID 
AND   CPC_BP.IP_TEL_ADDRESS_RLN_TYPE_CODE = 'BPNR' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_TRANS.CUSTOMER_PHONE_CURRENT CPC_HP 
ON  TD.INVOLVED_PARTY_ID = CPC_HP.INVOLVED_PARTY_ID 
AND   CPC_HP.IP_TEL_ADDRESS_RLN_TYPE_CODE = 'HPNR' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_TRANS.ORGANIZATION_CURRENT OC 
ON  TD.INVOLVED_PARTY_ID = OC.INVOLVED_PARTY_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_TRANS.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_CURRENT CAC_RA 
ON  TD.INVOLVED_PARTY_ID = CAC_RA.INVOLVED_PARTY_ID 
AND   CAC_RA.IP_ADDRESS_RLTNP_TYPE_CODE = '10' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_TRANS.CUSTOMER_WEB_ADDRESS_CURRENT CWAC_BW 
ON  TD.INVOLVED_PARTY_ID = CWAC_BW.INVOLVED_PARTY_ID 
AND   CWAC_BW.IP_WEB_ADDRESS_RLN_CODE = 'BW' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_TRANS.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_CURRENT CAC_PA 
ON  TD.INVOLVED_PARTY_ID = CAC_PA.INVOLVED_PARTY_ID 
AND   CAC_PA.IP_ADDRESS_RLTNP_TYPE_CODE = '1' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_TRANS.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_CURRENT CAC_EA 
ON  TD.INVOLVED_PARTY_ID = CAC_EA.INVOLVED_PARTY_ID 
AND   CAC_EA.IP_ADDRESS_RLTNP_TYPE_CODE = '70' 
WHERE TD.INFORMATION_DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Thanks for you patience to go through the code.

Regards,
Amit

Comment: All the LOJs are done on the semantic layer views

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to "tune" this query, approach your DBA to open an incident with Teradata support. You found a bug, don't try to fix it on your own.

And please follow the advice and don't submit it again (a 3610 is recorded in the logs including the user who caused it). There were enhancement requests (by DBAs) like "change the error message to **Hey stupid, I just told you not to submit again** when it's submitted a 2nd time and block the user the 3rd time"

Comment: Thanks Dieter for you reply :). I am not submitting this query again :). But, one thing i couldn't understand, what's the bug in this? can this be resolved by submitting this query through BTEQ?

Comment: @user3901666: *do not resubmit*  includes other tools :-)  It's a parser/optimizer problem...

Comment: Okay..Thanks Dieter.. you are wonderful :). I will ask my DBA's to raise an incident.

Comment: There is usually an incident created automatically by the Teradata GSC system ( auto create incident ). I suggest you ask  your system DBA's  (if they happen to be friendly  DBA's ) for the indent details or access to T@YS   and you can follow up on whats happening on that incident. For the most, the created incident will have more details about libraries involved that failed, this will give an idea of some sorts of what was happening behind .